# Python .get nested Json values

Tags: python, json, rest

I have a json file with the following example json entry:

```
{
            "title": "Test prod",
            "leafPage": true,
            "type": "product",
            "product": {
                "title": "test product",
                "offerPrice": "$19.95",
                "offerPriceDetails": {
                    "amount": 19.95,
                    "text": "$19.95",
                    "symbol": "$"
                },
                "media": [
                    {
                        "link": "http://www.test.com/cool.jpg",
                        "primary": true,
                        "type": "image",
                        "xpath": "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/img[1]"
                    }
                ],
                "availability": true
            },
            "human_language": "en",
            "url": "http://www.test.com"
        }
```

I can post via python script this to my test server perfectly when I use:

```
                     "text": entry.get("title"),
                     "url": entry.get("url"),
                     "type": entry.get("type"),
```

However I cannot get the following nested item to upload the values, how do I structure the python json call to get a nested python json entry?

Ive tried the below without success, I need to have it as .get because there are different fields currently in the json file and it errors out without the .get call.

```
                 "Amount": entry.get("product"("offerPrice"))
```

Any help on how to structure the nested json entry would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do:

```
"Amount": entry.get("product", {}).get("offerPrice")
```

`entry.get("product", {})` returns a product dictionary (or an empty dictionary if there is no `product` key).

Comment: Great thanks thats worked! so to get a nested object of products{ media I could use: entry.get("product", {}).get("media", {}).get("link") ?

Comment: Since media is a list then: entry.get("product", {}).get("media", [{}])[0].get("link")